# Intervalo de resultado

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Tenho uma tabela onde os registros são salvos a cada 3 segundos 24 horas por dia

Table: **myTable**

```
dado1       dado2       dado3          data
"135,05"    "134,69"    "135,10"    "2018-11-13 15:38:16"
"132,00"    "131,91"    "132,61"    "2018-11-13 15:38:24"
"130,63"    "130,57"    "131,21"    "2018-11-13 15:38:33"
"129,96"    "129,92"    "130,88"    "2018-11-13 15:38:42"
"129,69"    "129,55"    "130,77"    "2018-11-13 15:38:50"
"129,57"    "129,38"    "130,47"    "2018-11-13 15:38:59"
"129,44"    "129,27"    "130,60"    "2018-11-13 15:39:07"
"129,85"    "129,72"    "130,80"    "2018-11-13 15:39:16"
"129,91"    "129,74"    "131,24"    "2018-11-13 15:39:24"
"130,17"    "129,83"    "131,05"    "2018-11-13 15:39:33"
"130,36"    "130,00"    "131,21"    "2018-11-13 15:39:42"
"130,30"    "129,97"    "131,14"    "2018-11-13 15:39:50"
"130,47"    "130,00"    "131,25"    "2018-11-13 15:39:59"
"130,50"    "130,02"    "131,21"    "2018-11-13 15:40:07"
```

Gostaria de trazer entre esses resultados o tempo de **5 em 5 minutos**

Por exemplo

```
"130,47"    "130,00"    "131,25"    "2018-11-13 15:35:59"
"130,50"    "130,02"    "131,21"    "2018-11-13 15:40:07"
```

A data está a cada 5 minutos

Tentei fazer assim:

```
SELECT    dado1 
         ,dado2
         ,dado3
         ,data
     FROM myTable
    WHERE data BETWEEN DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(DATE(NOW()))-1 DAY) and last_day(DATE(NOW())) 
    AND  medidor = '62'
GROUP BY MINUTE(data)
HAVING 
    COUNT(data) <= 5
ORDER BY id
```

Mas não vem nada.

**[EDIT]**

Já consegui fazer isso aqui:

```
SELECT    SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(dado1), ',', 1) dado1
                ,SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(dado2), ',', 1) dado2
                ,SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(dado3), ',', 1) dado3
             ,DATE_FORMAT(data,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') dia
         FROM myTable
    WHERE data BETWEEN DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL DAYOFMONTH(DATE(NOW()))-1 DAY) and last_day(DATE(NOW())) 
     AND  medidor = '62'
    GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(data,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i')    
    ORDER BY id
```

Que traz os seguintes dados

```
"135.05"    "134.69"    "135.10"    "2018-11-13 15:38"
"130.47"    "130.00"    "131.25"    "2018-11-13 15:39"
"130.17"    "129.83"    "131.05"    "2018-11-13 15:40"
"129.64"    "129.57"    "130.77"    "2018-11-13 15:41"
"129.17"    "129.08"    "130.19"    "2018-11-13 15:42"
"129.61"    "129.36"    "130.55"    "2018-11-13 15:43"
"129.28"    "129.22"    "130.53"    "2018-11-13 15:44"
"129.71"    "129.64"    "130.69"    "2018-11-13 15:45"
"129.83"    "129.82"    "130.77"    "2018-11-13 15:46"
"130.22"    "130.03"    "131.24"    "2018-11-13 15:47"
"128.88"    "128.83"    "129.92"    "2018-11-13 15:48"
"128.75"    "128.75"    "129.92"    "2018-11-13 15:49"
"128.41"    "128.38"    "129.63"    "2018-11-13 15:50"
"129.32"    "129.22"    "130.25"    "2018-11-13 15:51"
```

Ou seja, os dados das linhas agrupados por minuto.

Agora falta trazer de 5 em 5 minutos

Comment: O que exatamente você quer dizer com `Agora falta trazer de 5 em 5 minutos` ? Uma função que a cada 5 minutos faz este select ou um "agrupamento" de 5 em 5 minutos ? Tentou utilizar algo como `DATE_ADD(sua_data, INTERVAL 5 minute)` ?

Comment: No exemplo que eu coloquei o primeiro tempo é: `2018-11-13 15:35:59` e o segundo é `2018-11-13 15:40:07` percebeu? o equivalente a 5 minutos depois

Comment: Quando você diz "de 5 em 5 minutos" quer dizer que o início do intervalo deve ser o instante no qual os minutos sejam múltiplos de 5? Note que em seu exemplo a diferença entre as datas não chega a 5 minutos completos, é 00:04:08.

Comment: Você tem registro de 3 em 3 seg. Mas quer pegar de 5 em 5 min a partir de uma data definida? É isso?

Comment: Criei a estrutura de exemplo no site http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/826e65/1

Comment: Não me parece uma situação para utilização do banco de dados para extração destas informações. Pois existem regras de negócio envolvidas. Então, em seu lugar, eu faria um loop utilizando a sua linguagem de programação e extrairia somente os dados necessários.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma forma seria usar uma variável:

```
SET @data := (SELECT data FROM tab1 ORDER BY data LIMIT 1);

SELECT * FROM tab1
WHERE data IN (
SELECT 
 (CASE WHEN data >= (SELECT data FROM tab1 WHERE data >= ADDTIME(@data, "00:05:00") LIMIT 1)
  THEN @data := data
  ELSE @data 
 END) AS data_5
FROM tab1 A
ORDER BY data)
```

---

Eu setei a variável com o primeiro registro da tabela, mas você pode fazer a partir de uma data específica também:

```
SET @data := (SELECT data FROM tab1 WHERE data > '2018-11-13 15:45' ORDER BY data LIMIT 1);
```

O que fiz na "query interna", foi tratar a variável com o `CASE` e sempre que  `data` for maior ou igual a "variável + 5min" (`ADDTIME(@data, "00:05:00")`), ela atualiza a variável e trás a data, caso não, ela mantém e trás a data já setada.

Depois só fiz um select trazendo essas datas a comparando.
Poderia usar um `GROUP BY` também.

---

### [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rB9metQDajtgZLapdk5GB6/0)

Answer (score 1):

Uma forma simples de resolver esse problema seria `GROUP BY CAST( DATE_FORMAT(data,'%Y%m%d%H%i') / 5 AS UNSIGNED )`

Answer (score 1):

Não sei se eu entendi bem o problema, mas segundo entendi quer de 5 em 5 minutos, sem interessar onde começa o intervalo de 5 minutos, então pode fazer assim:

```
SELECT * FROM tab1 
WHERE MOD( MINUTE( data ), 5 ) = 0  -- se o minuto for múltiplo de 5
AND data > '2018-11-13 15:40:07'    -- Se quiser maior que uma data especifica.
```

Veja a funcionar no [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qti1LWV7sakt64piXoVZG/0)